# VGG-19 Tensorflow 2.0 implementation

Tags: python-3.x, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, vgg-net

I am trying to implement VGG-19 CNN on CIFAR-10 dataset where the images are of dimension (32, 32, 3). The training set has 50000 images while the testing set has 10000 images. 
I am using Python 3.7 and TensorFlow 2.0. I have preprocessed the dataset by normalizing them-

```
# Normalize the training and testing datasets-
X_train /= 255.0
X_test /= 255.0
```

I have then designed a CNN-

```
def vgg_19():

    """
    Function to define the architecture of a convolutional neural network
    model following VGG-19 architecture for CIFAR-10 dataset.

    Vgg-19 architecture-
    64, 64, pool                 -- convolutional layers
    128, 128, pool               -- convolutional layers
    256, 256, 256, 256, max-pool -- convolutional layers
    512, 512, 512, 512, max-pool -- convolutional layers
    512, 512, 512, 512, avg-pool -- convolutional layers
    256, 256, 10                 -- fully connected layers

    Output: Returns designed and compiled convolutional neural network model
    """


    l = tf.keras.layers

    model = Sequential()

    model.add(
    Conv2D(
            filters = 64, kernel_size = (3, 3),
            activation='relu', kernel_initializer = tf.initializers.GlorotUniform(),
            strides = (1, 1), padding = 'same',
            input_shape=(32, 32, 3)
        )
    )

    model.add(
    Conv2D(
            filters = 64, kernel_size = (3, 3),
            activation='relu', kernel_initializer = tf.initializers.GlorotUniform(),
            strides = (1, 1), padding = 'same'
        )
    )

    model.add(
    MaxPooling2D(
            pool_size = (2, 2),
            strides = (2, 2)
        )
    )

    model.add(
    Conv2D(
            filters = 128, kernel_size = (3, 3),
            activation='relu', kernel_initializer = tf.initializers.GlorotUniform(),
            strides = (1, 1), padding = 'same'
        )
    )

    model.add(
    Conv2D(
            filters = 128, kernel_size = (3, 3),
            activation='relu', kernel_initializer = tf.initializers.GlorotUniform(),
            strides = (1, 1), padding = 'same'
        )
    )

    model.add(
    MaxPooling2D(
            pool_size = (2, 2),
            strides = (2, 2)
        )
    )

    model.add(
    Conv2D(
            filters = 256, kernel_size = (3, 3),
            activation='relu', kernel_initializer = tf.initializers.GlorotUniform(),
            strides = (1, 1), padding = 'same'
        )
    )

    model.add(
    Conv2D(
            filters = 256, kernel_size = (3, 3),
            activation='relu', kernel_initializer = tf.initializers.GlorotUniform(),
            strides = (1, 1), padding = 'same'
        )
    )

    model.add(
    Conv2D(
            filters = 256, kernel_size = (3, 3),
            activation='relu', kernel_initializer = tf.initializers.GlorotUniform(),
            strides = (1, 1), padding = 'same'
        )
    )

    model.add(
    Conv2D(
            filters = 256, kernel_size = (3, 3),
            activation='relu', kernel_initializer = tf.initializers.GlorotUniform(),
            strides = (1, 1), padding = 'same'
        )
    )

    model.add(
    MaxPooling2D(
            pool_size = (2, 2),
            strides = (2, 2)
        )
    )

    model.add(
    Conv2D(
            filters = 512, kernel_size = (3, 3),
            activation='relu', kernel_initializer = tf.initializers.GlorotUniform(),
            strides = (1, 1), padding = 'same'
        )
    )

    model.add(
    Conv2D(
            filters = 512, kernel_size = (3, 3),
            activation='relu', kernel_initializer = tf.initializers.GlorotUniform(),
            strides = (1, 1), padding = 'same'
        )
    )

    model.add(
    Conv2D(
            filters = 512, kernel_size = (3, 3),
            activation='relu', kernel_initializer = tf.initializers.GlorotUniform(),
            strides = (1, 1), padding = 'same'
        )
    )

    model.add(
    Conv2D(
            filters = 512, kernel_size = (3, 3),
            activation='relu', kernel_initializer = tf.initializers.GlorotUniform(),
            strides = (1, 1), padding = 'same'
        )
    )

    model.add(
    MaxPooling2D(
            pool_size = (2, 2),
            strides = (2, 2)
        )
    )

    model.add(
    Conv2D(
            filters = 512, kernel_size = (3, 3),
            activation='relu', kernel_initializer = tf.initializers.GlorotUniform(),
            strides = (1, 1), padding = 'same'
        )
    )

    model.add(
    Conv2D(
            filters = 512, kernel_size = (3, 3),
            activation='relu', kernel_initializer = tf.initializers.GlorotUniform(),
            strides = (1, 1), padding = 'same'
        )
    )

    model.add(
    Conv2D(
            filters = 512, kernel_size = (3, 3),
            activation='relu', kernel_initializer = tf.initializers.GlorotUniform(),
            strides = (1, 1), padding = 'same'
        )
    )

    model.add(
    Conv2D(
            filters = 512, kernel_size = (3, 3),
            activation='relu', kernel_initializer = tf.initializers.GlorotUniform(),
            strides = (1, 1), padding = 'same'
        )
    )


    model.add(
    AveragePooling2D(
        pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)
    )
    )


    '''
    model.add(
        MaxPooling2D(
            pool_size = (2, 2),
            strides = (2, 2)
        )
    )
    '''

    model.add(Flatten())


    model.add(
    Dense(
            units = 256, activation='relu'
        )
    )

    model.add(
    Dense(
            units = 256, activation='relu'
        )
    )

    '''
    model.add(
    Dense(
            units = 1000, activation='relu'
        )
    )
    '''

    model.add(
    Dense(
            units = 10, activation='softmax'
        )
    )


    # Compile pruned CNN-
    model.compile(
        loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
        # optimizer='adam',
        optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.9),
        metrics=['accuracy']
    )

    return model
```

However, when I try to train it-

```
history = orig_model.fit(
        x = X_train, y = y_train,
        batch_size = batch_size,
        epochs = num_epochs,
        verbose = 1,
        # callbacks = callback,
        validation_data = (X_test, y_test),
        shuffle = True
    )
```

The designed CNN gives a validation accuracy of about 9%.

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The abysmally low validation accuracy is due to Glorot initializer. After changing it to 'he normal', the VGG-19 CNN starts learning and reaches about 77-79% validation accuracy.